# Built in Bluetooth on Raspberry Pi 3 Windows IoT - adapter not found

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I have a Raspberry Pi3 running Windows IoT version 10.0.14931.1000. The Raspberry Pi 3 onboard bluetooth adapter is supposed to be supported in this version of Windows IoT.

When I use the web portal to search for Bluetooth devices nothing is found, and my Raspberry Pi does not appear to be discoverable. When use Windows IoT Remote Client to connect to the Raspberry Pi and look at the Bluetooth settings it says: "No usable Bluetooth adapter can be found on this computer: The device is not ready for use. (Excep_FromHResult 0x800710DF)".

Is there something else I need to do to enable Bluetooth on the device?

I could try reinstalling Windows, but before I do that I wanted to know if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I tested it on Windows IoT version 14393 and Bluetooth works well. Have you tried this version?

Comment: Interesting that with me, the onboard bluetooth adapter works with 10.0.14931.1000 on RP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Windows (10.0.14393.0) on the Raspberry Pi 3 and Bluetooth is now working. I can only assume that because I started with an insider build that did not support Bluetooth it has got itself into an unexpected state.
If it was full blown Windows I suspect deleting the device and reinstalling it would have done the trick, but that's not an option on IoT.